# Horizontal scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have situation like this:

```
<ul class=".pages-list">
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="to_the_right">
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
    <li><img src="#"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="controls">
    <li class="left">◄</li>
    <li class="right">►</li>
</ul>
```

.secondclass is accepting new images when added.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('.to_the_right').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var width = $this.outerWidth();
      //$this.after($('<div style="width:' + width + 'px" >'));
     $('.to_the_right').css("width", (width - 230));
    console.log(width)

   if (window.location.href === "http://www.fractal-arch.com/projects/") {
      //    $('#full_width').css("width", (1519 + width));
        }   

  });
});
```

I have coded page so it widens once new li is added in .to_the_right ul

```
/*project Page */
ul.pages-list li, ul.to_the_right li {
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
}
ul.pages-list li a, ul.to_the_right li a {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
    background: #0000006e;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 82px 45px 0 45px;
}
ul.pages-list li:hover a, ul.to_the_right li:hover a {
    display: block;
}
ul.pages-list li img, ul.to_the_right li img {
    max-width: 220px;
}
ul.pages-list{
    margin-left: 90px;
    width: 1151px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
}
ul.to_the_right{
    float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}
.page-id-447 #full_width {
  /*  width: 3000px; */
    max-width: 3000px;
}
```

I have right and left arrows at page bottom.

I wonder how would I scroll this left/right on arrow click?
 this is actual look of the page+ newly added content 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ4vb.jpg)

or how could i scroll window bar (whic appears eventually when more lis are added) by clicking these arrows.
Both answers are fine.

Comment: you need to post your complete code necessary to recreate the situation you are talking about (HTML, CSS, maybe JS)

Comment: ok, here it goes

Answer (score 0):

The solution you seem to be looking for sounds a lot like a "carousel" -- sideways scrollable content inside of some div or element.

If you're not already using Bootstrap or some sort of JavaScript platform that might implement its own carousel, you could try something like this library to accomplish this:

[Slick jQuery Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Hope this helps but let me know if you need more help!

Cheers.

Comment: It is kind of carousel but my trouble is that it is with 2 ul tags actual look is 2 rows by x elements, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Let me see if if I'm understanding you -- you have two UL lists, one of which has dynamic width and changes size. Both are in the SAME carousel "card" and your typical carousel card might have dynamic-width lists, too. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, please check updated code and attached img under "enter image description here"

Comment: What I actually want is to simulate window drag l/r by clicking